# Graphite django-admin.py raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty or No module named 'graphite'

Tags: graphite

I am trying to install Graphite on Ubuntu 16.04.  django-admin.py raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

If I change export GRAPHITE_ROOT=/opt/graphite to:

```
export GRAPHITE_ROOT=/opt/graphite/webapp
```

I not longer get SECRET_KEY error but I get:

```
File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'graphite'
```

I followed [these instructions](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-virtualenv.html) and executed the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libcairo2-dev libffi-dev build-essential

wget https://launchpad.net/graphite/0.9/0.9.10/+download/graphite-web-0.9.10.tar.gz

wget https://launchpad.net/graphite/0.9/0.9.10/+download/carbon-0.9.10.tar.gz

wget https://launchpad.net/graphite/0.9/0.9.10/+download/whisper-0.9.10.tar.gz

wget https://launchpad.net/graphite/0.9/0.9.10/+download/check-dependencies.py


tar xvf whisper-0.9.10.tar.gz 
tar xvf carbon-0.9.10.tar.gz 
tar xvf graphite-web-0.9.10.tar.gz 

cd carbon-0.9.10/

sudo python setup.py install

cd whisper-0.9.10/
sudo python setup.py install

cd graphite-web-0.9.10/
sudo python setup.py install

sudo virtualenv /opt/graphite
source /opt/graphite/bin/activate

sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /opt/graphite

pip install Django 
pip install pytz scandir 
pip install django-tagging 
pip install pycairo

sudo apt install apache2

wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.6.5.tar.gz

tar xvf 4.6.5.tar.gz 
cd mod_wsgi-4.6.5/
sudo ./configure 
sudo make install

cd /opt/graphite/conf
cp graphite.wsgi.example graphite.wsgi

cd /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite
cp local_settings.py.example local_settings.py

export $GRAPHITE_ROOT=/opt/graphite

PYTHONPATH=$GRAPHITE_ROOT/webapp /opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=graphite.settings
```

Produces this error:

```
File "/opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 182, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I believe the reason for this is that django gets installed both in the virtualenv and in the $DJANGO_HOME.  The instructions say when using virtualenv put the full path to django-admin.py, which I did.

Thus is it reading global_settings.py from the wrong location or it's looking for local_settings.py in the wrong location.

```
./opt/graphite/bin/django-admin.py
./opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
```

Both of these have:

> SECRET_KEY = ''

Plus I tried to put a value in both, which should not be required if you look at the code which throws the error it only looks for the presence of the field and not whether it is empty.

> SECRET_KEY = '1232323'

```
./opt/graphite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py
./home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py
```

Here's the code throwing the error in /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py:

```
if not self.SECRET_KEY:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

Answer (score 0):

0.9.10 is very old version (May 2012, over 7 years ago) and it doesn't support Python 3.
If you want install Graphite from sources please try latest release (1.1.5) instead.

But you can also install it from packages (although bit older version, 0.9.15 in Ubuntu 16.04). You can use more distro-specific manual written by community. E.g. https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/install-and-configure-graphite-on-ubuntu/ or https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-graphite-on-ubuntu-16-04

You can also try [Graphite in Docker](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#docker) - it's quick and convenient way of running latest version with minimal hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you activated the virtualenv *after* installing graphite-web and carbon and whisper, but you need to do so *before* installing them, if using a virtualenv.